Summarize query table
I have this starting table which is called InventoryItem which shows inventory levels in my warehouse and bin locations:



Inventory ID
Warehouse
Warehouse Location
Qty




11017
Nashville
Dock
10


11017
Nashville
Hold
5


11017
Nashville
A1
13


11017
New York
Hold
20


11119
Chicago
Hold
5


11119
New York
C34
6


11119
New York
Hold
20



I want to end up with the following view which essentially shows what is on hand (any warehouse locations not equal to Hold) and what is on hold (any warehouse locations equal to Hold):



Inventory ID
Warehouse
Qty on Hand(Not Equal to Hold)
Qty on Hold(Equal to hold)




11017
Nashville
23
5


11017
New York
0
20


11119
Chicago
0
5


11119
New York
6
20



Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You could create a PXProjection aggregate bql for not on hold and another PXProjection aggrege for on old. Then you can have your main query on INItemWarehouse left joined to these projections.

I think you should also clarify if you are looking to do this in SQL or within the Acumatica framework (preferred method). This would help you get the answer you are looking for.

this will do it:
select [Inventory ID], Warehouse,
    [Qty on Hand] = sum(iif([Warehouse Location] != 'Hold', Qty, 0)),
    [Qty on Hold] = sum(iif([Warehouse Location] = 'Hold', Qty, 0))
from InventoryItem
group by [Inventory ID], Warehouse

..since you're new to SQL Server you might like to know how you could use a bunch of advanced language features to write the same query in a much more complicated way, eg:
with InventoryByHoldState as (
    select i.[Inventory ID], i.Warehouse, s.HoldState, Qty = sum(i.Qty)
    from InventoryItem i cross apply (select
        HoldState = iif(i.[Warehouse Location] = 'Hold',
            'Qty on Hold', 'Qty on Hand')) s
    group by i.[Inventory ID], i.Warehouse, s.HoldState)

select p.* from InventoryByHoldState
pivot (sum(Qty) for HoldState in ([Qty on Hand], [Qty on Hold])) p


You should explore accessing InventoryAllocDetEnq, setting the filter with your inventory values and availability rules to come up with Quantities
